# Twilio: Forward call to different SIP Endpoints under the same phone number based on the menu choise

Tags: twilio, sip, twilio-twiml

I have a phone number on twilio with a SIP domain and right now all incoming calls go straight to a single SIP Endpoint.

I'm trying to setup a function so that during the call the user gets presented with a menu choice, and depending on their choice (1/2/3) gets routed to different SIP Endpoints under the same number.

Is there a way to do it using twiml/built in functions?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is with [Twilio Studio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/user-guide). The [Connect Call To Widget](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library/connect-call) allows you to connect to different SIP URI's and the [Gather Input on Call Widget](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library/gather-input-call) allows you to provide a message (either Text-to-Speech or .mp3/.wav) and collect touch tone (DTMF) or Speech Input from the calling party. Once collected, you can use the [Split Based on Widget](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library/split-based-on) to route to the relevant Connect To Widget. All this is done via drag and drop widgets so I suggest that approach.